# The sum of keys in an array of objects for each day

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a problem: I am trying to calculate the sum of each key for each day. However, I cannot get the desired result. Perhaps you can help fix the error?

**This is my way of solving the problem:**

```
const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find((i) => i.date === curr.date);

  if (node) {
    return [...acc.filter((i) => i.date !== curr.date), { ...node, date: curr.date, [curr.source]: [curr.source].length + 1 }];
  }

  return [...acc, { date: curr.date, [curr.source]: [curr.source].length }];
}, []);
```

```
const input = [
  {
    date: "01-01-2021",
    source: "TT",
  },
  {
    date: "01-01-2021",
    source: "TT",
  },
  {
    date: "02-01-2021",
    source: "FB",
  },
  {
    date: "02-01-2021",
    source: "TT",
  },
];
```

**Expected result: **

```
const output = [
  {
    date: "01-01-2021",
    TT: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "02-01-2021",
    TT: 1,
    FB: 1,
  },
];
```

And this is what I get now:

```
const result = [
  {
    date: "01-01-2021",
    TT: 2,
  },
  {
    date: "02-01-2021",
    TT: 2,
    FB: 1,
  },
];
```

Comment: can you lodash library ?

Comment: what is the difference of the both results? only the name?

Comment: @NinaScholz The wrong `TT` value for `02-01-2021`

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya yea sure

Comment: Search on SO for _"array of objects group by property"_. The result won't be a perfect match. But translating the properties of an object into separate arrays is not that complicated.

Comment: @NinaScholz In the number of occurrences of the name per day

Comment: Instead of trying to reduce and find and filter, start with some "dumber" code. Just have a forEach that builds up an object, where each key in the object is a date, with an object value based on those `source` properties. Then once you have that, turning that into an array is far less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is the following part in your if-statement:

```js
[curr.source].length + 1
```

Here you're creating an array with `curr.source` (1 element), grabbing its length which will always be `1`, and then adding `1` to it, giving you 2. Instead, you can change this line to be:

```js
(node[curr.source] ?? 0) + 1
```

This will grab the source's value from your found node, and it will add one to the current value. If the value hasn't been set on the node, it will default to `0` by using `?? 0` (here `??` is the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) - it could be replaced with `||` if you need better browser support). I would also suggest defaulting your `node` value to an empty object if it isn't found when using `.find()` by using `?? {}`, which will allow you to remove your inner if-statement and run that portion of code each time:

```js
const input = [ { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT", }, { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT", }, { date: "02-01-2021", source: "FB", }, { date: "02-01-2021", source: "TT", }, ];

const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find((i) => i.date === curr.date) ?? {};
  return [...acc.filter((i) => i.date !== curr.date), { ...node, date: curr.date, [curr.source]: (node[curr.source] ?? 0) + 1 }];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Another option that would be more efficient is to build a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)/object that is keyed by your `date` key from your objects. For each iteration of your reduce method you can get the current accumulated object at your current date from the Map, and update the source count based on the current source. You can then transform the Map into an array of your accumulated objects by using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on that Map's [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator:

```js
const input = [ { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT", }, { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT", }, { date: "02-01-2021", source: "FB", }, { date: "02-01-2021", source: "TT", }, ];

const res = Array.from(input.reduce((acc, {date, source}) => {
  const seen = acc.get(date) ?? {};
  return acc.set(date, {...seen, date, [source]: (seen[source] ?? 0) + 1});
}, new Map).values());
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group with an object and increment the given source property.

```js
const input = [
  { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT" },
  { date: "01-01-2021", source: "TT" },
  { date: "02-01-2021", source: "FB" },
  { date: "02-01-2021", source: "TT" }
];

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((r, { date, source }) => {
  r[date] ??= { date };
  r[date][source] = (r[date][source] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```